# vim: delete (cut) and put (paste) from command line

Tags: vim

To yank and put below a specific line without pre-positioning the cursor, one could use the following syntax: `:2,6t11`. But what if I want to delete the original lines in the process?

By the way, if you could point me to a web resource for command-line text manipulation, I'll be grateful. I really like the command I cited above, but my attempt to extrapolate from it has been unsuccessful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`:t` copies and pastes, you can use `:m` to move the text, e.g. `:2,6m11`. `:d` will just delete the text.

You can read more about a command and look around for related commands in the vim builtin help system, try starting at `:h :t`.